# jQuery Slide Panel on Mouseover

Tags: jquery

How can I make this sliding panel example to slide down on mouseover and slide back in on mouseout instead of using the click function?

See the example here: http://www.webdesignerwall.com/demo/jquery/simple-slide-panel.html

```
$(".btn-slide").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).toggleClass("active"); return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [hover](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) function. This should be close.

```
function slide() {
  $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
  return false;
}

$(".btn-slide").hover(slide, slide);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

$("#sliderbar").hover(
 function(){
       $("#sliderbar").stop().animate({left:"-200px"},{queue:false,duration:300});
 },
 function() {
      $("#sliderbar").stop().animate({left:"0px"},{queue:false,duration:300});
 });